# Will a template specialized for const char * accept char * as well?

Tags: c++, templates, constants, template-specialization

Will a template specialized for `const char *` catch `char *` as well?

For example:

```
template <typename T> class Foo { /* ... */ };
template <> class Foo<const char *> { /* ... */ };
```

Will `Foo<char *>` refer to the generic template or the specialized one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

template classes and functions only match with *exact* matches, so in your case, `Foo<char*>` will refer to the generic, because `char*` and `const char*` are different types.  This gets even more confusing for functions, because sometimes references are added to the types: `const char*&`.

To make a class template that accepts pointer variants is sort of complex, but often works more or less like this:

```
template <typename T, typename allowed=void> class Foo { /* ... */ };

template <typename T> 
class Foo<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, char*>::value || 
                           std::is_same<T, const char*>::value
                           >::type> { /* ... */ };
```

Depending on what you're doing, you may need `std::remove_reference<T>` as well.

Comment: So would I have to create a specialization for each possible equivalent type?

Comment: @Matt: No, you can use a partial specialization to handle multiple types. Add a second template parameter with `typename = void` in the generic, then `typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, char*>::value || std::is_same<T, const char*>::value>::type` in the partial specialization.

Comment: Actually, that prints [`"B"`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/817bc782013ebfa1). Did you mean to make `thing` a `char *`?

Comment: @T.C.: No, I honestly thought it would bind with the reference :/  I'll think of another example then

Comment: is convertable probably better here than chain of `is_same`.

Comment: @Yakk: Depends entirely on Matt's use case.  I thought he wanted to match `char*` and `const char*` but nothing else.  Could be your way as well.